# Handle checkboxes with strongly typed views in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What is the Correct(TM) way to handle checkboxes with asp.net MVC and strongly typed views. I have a class 'Bar' that has a member 'foo'. 'foo' is type 'byte'.

Now what I would like do, is have something like this in controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Page( Bar bar ) 
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {    
      SaveChanges(bar);
 ...
```

And something like this in the view

```
<%=Html.CheckBox( "foo", Model.foo) %>
```

Of course the above code doesn't work, because DefaultModelBinder(?) doesn't know how to convert output from Checkbox (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms)) to byte so ModelState.IsValid is false.

How to make it work? Custom Model Binders? How? Seems like a simple problem, but I've failed to find a comprehensive guide how to do this.  (yes, I know I suck at googling :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Model - convert the Byte to a Bool property.  You can still store in the database as a byte.  Just make the get/set use a bool and convert there.