# asp.net MVC checkbox headache!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have seen lots of questions relating to this topic.

I am using asp.net MVC 1.0

Problem area

If I use

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("Status", true) %>
```

Then why It renders like

```
<input checked="checked" id="Status" name="Status" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="Status" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

I put this in foreach loop and I have 5 rows.

when I submit form with **true,true,true,false,false**
then I get `true,false,true,false,true,false,false,false`

i.e. for false =>  false.

for true => true,false

If I use

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" name="Status" checked="checked" />
```

Then I don't get unchecked one's.

so how do I overcome form this problem?

Please don't post answer with using loop in formcollection object and checking each key!

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't the elegant one but this is what I did:

collection["response"].Replace("true,false", "true").Split(',').ToList();

Answer (score 1):

In your example, when you submit form with **true,true,true,false,false** and you get

```
true,false,true,false,true,false,false,false
```

it is interesting to note that you are not actually getting eight values back, but five arrays that merely looks like this is the case because all of the values are joined.
I know you asked to not get a loop for your answer, but I can use one to demonstrate what is really happening here:

```
foreach (string key in postedForm.AllKeys) {
    // "value" will contain a joined/comma-separated list of ALL values,
    // including something like "true,false" for a checked checkbox.
    string value = postedForm[key].GetValue;
    // "values" will be an array, where you can access its first element,
    // e.g., values[0], to get the actual intended value.
    string[] values = postedForm.GetValues(key);
}
```

So, for your checked boxes, you'll get a values array with two elements, and for unchecked boxes, you'll get just a single-element array.

Thus, to answer your question *how do you overcome this problem*, the answer lies in using GetValues rather than GetValue, and thinking of your posted fields as arrays rather than strings.

Best of luck!

Comment: MVC3 with .Net4.0 doesn't have GetValues

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think having to check for "true,false" everywhere on the server is a pain. I wrote a jquery fix that will remove the extra hidden field created by the Html.Checkbox helper when a box is checked, then add it back if the box is unchecked. Server values will always be "true" or "false". Checkbox lists are kind of subjective in how you want them to act, which I discuss, but I'm removing "false" from the value set, which means the form value will be excluded if all boxes in the list are unchecked.

http://www.mindstorminteractive.com/blog/?p=386

I've had pretty good success using this technique. Please let me know if you try it out and have issues.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do your own model binding for the CheckBox values.

Get the list of values from the FormCollection or Request.Form for that CheckBox id and replace true,false with true:

```
string chkBoxString = Request.Form["checkboxID"].Replace("true,false", "true")
```

Now you have a list of whether a CheckBox was selected or not.... do the rest yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

It renders so because default binder requires the FormCollection to have a value for nonnullable parameters. Using this technique we are sure that the value will be sent even the checkbox is not checked (by default the value sent only when it's checked). If you use this controller method with just one html input you'll get error on form post with unchecked checkbox (value of checkbox will not be posted and binder will not know what to use for value of isItemSelected):

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(bool isItemSelected)
```

You can try use something like this with just one html input:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(bool? isItemSelected)
```

But in this case isItemSelected will be null or will be true. And it will never become false.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are couple of ways you can do based on your requirement.

I use this method.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<%= item.ID %>" name="check" checked="checked")" />
```

This is may checkboxes.

On server side I will also have array of ID's of item in the model.
So I check it whether it is in array

```
var strArray = form["checkbox"]; //Request.form["checkbox"] or "FormCollection form" in action parameter;  array of ID's in comma separated string.
```

Different people have different tests.

Answer (score 0):

> 

this was intended to use for just just simple CheckBox, what you want is checkboxList, which is not yet cover in the API of ASP.net MVC

If you looking for some thing like checkboxlist, maybe you should write your own helper, provide you understand HTML well..

That's it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Easier just to check whether AttemptedValue.Contains("true") - it will, if it's checked, not if it's unchecked....

Answer (score 0):

in the View :

```
<input id="radio5" type="checkbox" name="rb_abc" value="5"/>
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult YourForm(FormCollection fc)
 { 
      if (fc["rb_abc"] == "on")
      {
           //Hey .. you have selected a Radio Button.. just kidding.. its a CheckBox
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get checkbox value even it is true or false

```
var boolValue = bool.Parse(collection.GetValues("checkboxID")[0])
```