# Method to Allow User to Select Multiple Items - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I have an e-commerce system that allows a product to have multiple categories. In the admin user interface, I'm going to allow the administrator to be able to add as many categories to the product as he would like. What are some good ways to accomplish this? I don't want to do a select-list where the user has to hold down the control key, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a row of checkboxes in a table of categories to perform the selection.

[ASP.Net MVC - Handle Multiple Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795812/asp-net-mvc-handle-multiple-checkboxes)

Comment: +1: The select box with multiple is anti-usability. Checkboxes is a good solution!