# Model binding postback data to a controller action parameter of type List<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, model-binding, generic-list

I have a strong type view of type

```
List<List<MyViewModelClass>>
```

The outer list will always have two lists of `List<MyViewModelClass>`. For each of the two outer lists I want to display a group of checkboxes. Each set can have an arbitrary number of choices.

My view model class looks similar to this:

```
public class MyViewModelClass
{
    public Area Area { get; set; }

    public bool IsGeneric { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

So the final view will look something like:

---

Please select those that apply:

**First set of choices:**

- <kbd>x</kbd> Option 1
- <kbd>x</kbd> Option 2
- <kbd>x</kbd> Option 3
- etc.

**Second set of choices:**

- <kbd>x</kbd> Second Option 1
- <kbd>x</kbd> Second Option 2
- <kbd>x</kbd> Second Option 3
- <kbd>x</kbd> Second Option 4
- etc.

---

Checkboxes should display `MyViewModelClass.Area.Name`, and their value should be related to `MyViewModelClass.Area.Id`. Checked state is of course related to `MyViewModel.IsChecked`.

### Question

I wonder how should I use `Html.CheckBox()` or `Html.CheckBoxFor()` helper to display my checkboxes? I have to get these values back to the server on a postback of course.

I would like to have my controller action like one of these:

```
public ActionResult ConsumeSelections(List<List<MyViewModelClass>> data)
{
    // process data
}

public ActionResult ConsumeSelections(List<MyViewModelClass> first, List<MyViewModelClass> second)
{
    // process data
}
```

If it makes things simpler, I could make a separate view model type like:

```
public class Options
{
    public List<MyViewModelClass> First { get; set; }

    public List<MyViewModelClass> Second { get; set; }
}
```

As well as changing my first version of controller action to:

```
public ActionResult ConsumeSelections(Options data)
{
    // process data
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

It turns out this is not so complicated at all. All you have to do is name your controls appropriately and everything will be bound together as it should be. So. Whatever your controls, they should always be named like:

```
name="first[0].propName"
name="first[1].propName"
name="first[2].propName"
name="first[3].propName"
...

// or
name="first[0].data[0].property"
name="first[0].data[1].property"
name="first[0].data[2].property"
...
name="first[1].data[0].property"
name="first[1].data[1].property"
...
```

All these will get bound to `List<SomeType> first` controller action parameter (the second one has another collection inside a collection).

**Very important note**
If you add/remove these controls dynamically using Javascript, you have to make sure, that indexes are consecutive starting from 0, and not having any gaps. And you will have a nice working app with dynamic number of elements in a collection.

You can read about it in [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/preparing-list-of-objects-so-they-can.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I create a type (Model) that "models" the view that I want to create.
i.e.

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public List<Option> General { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Others { get; set; }

    //Some Methods and other properties
}
public FooController :...
{
    private FooViewModel fooViewModel = new FooViewModel();
}
```

Edit:
Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms), as it's exactly what you want!

Comment: Ok. This is just a view model (I suggested it my question as well). How do you consume data in it? Displaying data is simple, but how to put data on a view when you want a FORM with checkboxes to get back to the server.

Comment: I have updated my post to include a link to a post that I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well to some extent it is, but it's still custom binding in the end. I edited my question to also include my action method...