# ASP MVC add textboxes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, textbox

I am new to jQuery, but I would like to have a button that when clicked will add more textboxes to a page. I have three textboxes that contain data of the same type and if the user has more data of the same type to enter, I would like to pop up three more textboxes.

What would be the best way to go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("<input type='text' name='as_it_should_be'>").append(...).
```

Check jQuery documentation.

Regarding Asp.net MVC model binding to collections of data, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400391) may help as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading [Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) by Steve Sanderson. It explains how to achieve what I believe you are trying to do.

Comment: That is basically what I need. But I need to do it without a strongly typed view because there are multiple types of data on the same page.