# asp.net mvc checkbox detailview

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use checkbox in my detail view for the  bit true or false field. How would i do that .

### EDIT

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Groups group = _db.Groups.First(c => c.int_GroupId == id);
    var checkBox = Request.Form["bit_Active"];
    if (checkBox == "on")
    {

    }

    return View(group);
}
```

View:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bit_Active" />
```

How will I pass the database value to the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to handle checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms)