# Getting all selected checkboxes from a FormCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controls, webforms, checkbox, formcollection

I have a form which contains a whole bunch of checkboxes and some other types of control too. I need to retrieve the names of each selected checkbox.

What is the best way to do this? Can I do it with a linq query maybe?

So in pseudocode, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
var names = formCollection
               .Where(c => c is Checkbox && c.Checked)
               .Select(c => c.Name);
```

**Update** It seems the way MVC submits checkboxes is different from how a normal form would behave, as an hidden field is also rendered. I found the details here: [How to handle checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms)

Anywho, I've got it working with the help of that thread and the answer from BuildStarted below. The following code did the trick.

```
var additionalItems = form.AllKeys
       .Where(k => form[k].Contains("true") && k.StartsWith("addItem"))
               .Select(k => k.Substring(7));
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. I normally just use the built in model binding and never really looked into detail what is output to the html with regards to checkboxes.

Comment: Nice example, I just updated code in my project for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately that type of information isn't available in the collection. However if you prepend all your checkboxes with something like `<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_somevalue' />` then you can run a query like

```
var names = formCollection.AllKeys.Where(c => c.StartsWith("checkbox"));
```

Since only the checked values will be posted back you don't need to validate that they're checked.

Here's one that grabs only checked values

```
var names = formCollection.AllKeys.Where(c => c.StartsWith("test") && 
                        formCollection.GetValue(c) != null &&
                        formCollection.GetValue(c).AttemptedValue == "1");
```

Comment: I'm definitely getting ALL checkboxes posted back, not just the checked ones.

Comment: That's strange. A quick test reveals that isn't the case. Might be specific html causing that. but the `<input type='checkbox' name='somename' />` form doesn't seem to work for me. However I've updated the answer

Comment: I've got it figured out now. Updated my question with a few more details. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the old questions not active for years but I stumbled on it. My problem was that I have an array of check boxes - let's say the name is 'IsValid' and wanted to get the status of each of the check boxes (my project was in MVC 5). On form submit i did the loop of form collection and got the values as...

```
if (key.Contains("IsValid"))
                    sV = (string[])collection.GetValue(key.ToString()).RawValue;
```

Since on form post the hidden field value was also posted with the checked check boxes; the array contained one additional value of 'false' for ONLY checked check box. To get rid of those i used following function; I hope that it helps somebody and if my approach is wrong then a better solution would be helpful to me as well!

```
sV = FixCheckBoxValue(sV);

        private string[] FixCheckBoxValue(string[] sV)
    {
        var iArrayList = new List<string>(sV);

        for (int i = 0; i < iArrayList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (iArrayList[i].ToString() == "true")
            {
                iArrayList.RemoveAt(i + 1);
            }                
        }
        return iArrayList.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the post about the array of checkboxes, you could initially filter out the checkboxes by name.

```
var keys = formCollection.AllKeys.Where(x => x.StartsWith("IsValid");
```

Then you could just loop through them as a collection.