# EF4 - Is it possible to add a property to an entity which won't be reflected in the db?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

In the epic quest of me getting my Create and Edit methods working for my complex model, I've come up with an idea - adding a boolean IsSelected property to one of my entity classes for use with checkboxes in my views.  Is it possible?  Would something as simple as

```
public partial class Platform : SomeBaseClass
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works. Have you tried it?

That said, I recommend dedicated view models.

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it as I'm away from my dev computer.  I just figured it was the easiest way to solve my problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196247/mvc2-model-binding-w-many-to-many-at-the-cusp  Unless you have a better/cleaner solution.

Comment: I agree with stuntz, instead of putting isselected in the entity make a platformitemviewmodel and wrap your entity in that with an extra isselected property.  this will keep your model cleaner.