# MVC3 form, single form in view.. not strongly typed - howto parse results

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a form.. basically a questionnaire with 18 questions.

They are all radio button groups (select 1 to 5).

What is the simplest way to get the selected radiobutton out of the group (each button group is setup with the same name attribute).

It is not strongly typed.. i'm just not sure how i access the values in the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not strongly typed.

Here's your biggest problem. So strongly type it ...

... to a view model of course:

```
public class AnswerViewModel
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

Then write a controller which would be responsible for showing the questionnaire form and processing the results of this form:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // TODO: those are obviously going to come from some data store
        // or whatever comes to your mind
        var model = new[]
        {
            new QuestionViewModel 
            {
                Title = "Question 1",
                PossibleAnswers = new[] 
                { 
                    "Answer 1 to question 1", 
                    "Answer 2 to question 1" 
                }
            },
            new QuestionViewModel 
            {
                Title = "Question 2",
                PossibleAnswers = new[]
                { 
                    "Answer 1 to question 2", 
                    "Answer 2 to question 2",
                    "Answer 3 to question 2",
                }
            },
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<QuestionViewModel> questions)
    {
        // TODO : Process the answers. Here for each element of the 
        // questions collection you could use the Answer property
        // in order to fetch the answer from the user.
        return Content("Thqnks for submitting the questionnaire", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

and then let's move on to the view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<QuestionViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit answers" />
}
```

and finally the editor template for a question which will be rendered for each element of our model collection (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/QuestionViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model QuestionViewModel

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Title)
@foreach (var item in Model.PossibleAnswers)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Answer, item)
    @item
}
```

Comment: hey thanks.. it's making some sense. What limitations are there with the radiobuttonfor in terms of layout? I need to be able to control how the 5 possible answers are displayed.. padding, width etc.

Comment: @rwfresh, there are no limitations. You could lay them out as you wish. I am not specialist in web design but you could group them in divs, apply each radio button a specific CSS class, etc ...

Comment: Hi Darin, i cannot get this to work. My model has Questions and possible answers. I need to create radiobuttongroups where the name is all the same(question1) and the id for the radiobuttons would be some unique variation. My model has a collection of questions. How do you work with this?

Answer (score 1):

In your HttpPost Action, you can accept a "[FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx)" type as a parameter. It will have all the data your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can access these through the [`FormCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) which contains all the values that are posted:

```
public ActionResult QuestionnaireAction(FormCollection formCollection)
{
   foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
   {
      var value = formCollection[key];
      // etc.
   }

   foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
   {
       var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
       // etc.
   }
}
```

However, make sure to read the post [How to handle checkboxes in ASP.NET MVC forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms) first as checkboxes can be weird in MVC if you don't understand how they work.