# Rendering Nullable Bool as CheckBox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new from WebForms to MVC. I have view model field with the type `bool?` and, by default, `EditorFor()` renders this field as a DropDownList with a "Not Set" option. I would prefer to render it as a CheckBox and, if the value is null, just set it to unchecked.

The field name is `RFP.DatesFlexible` and so I wrote the following markup in my view:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="RFP_DatesFlexible" name="RFP.DatesFlexible" />
<label for="RFP_DatesFlexible">My Dates are Flexible</label>
```

But this doesn't work. The result is always null and `ModelState.IsValid` is false.

Can anyone say how I could make this work?

**EDIT**

This is the code I ended up with, which appears to work fine.

```
@Html.CheckBox("RFP.DatesFlexible", Model.RFP.DatesFlexible ?? false)
@Html.Label("RFP.DatesFlexible", "My Dates are Flexible")
```

The label is correctly associated with the checkbox so that clicking the text will toggle the checkbox.

Comment: Thank's for the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

Models:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ViewModel2 RDP { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel2
{
    public bool? DatesFlexible { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult TestBool()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel { RDP = new ViewModel2() });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestBool(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model mvc_testing_2.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBox("RDP.DatesFlexible", 
        Model.RDP.DatesFlexible != null && (bool)Model.RDP.DatesFlexible)

    <input type="submit" value="go" />
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The first argument is an error because it can't convert bool? to bool. And if I typecast it to a bool, I get an error because it's not a property.

Comment: Alright, then change it to this: `@Html.CheckBox("DatesFlexible", Model.DatesFlexible != null && (bool)Model.DatesFlexible)`. This works, I just tested it. (Is RFP a property of another model? Model.RFP.DatesFlexible? If so, you'll probably need to name the input how you have it in your question, I can't remember off-hand)

Comment: That compiles--thanks. However, the field is still `null` when the page is submitted. Somehow, it's not picking up that the control is associated with the field. (The field is Model.RFP.DatesFlexible.)

Comment: Hmm, still seems to work fine for me when I rename the field to RFP.DatesFlexible (and change the Model.DatesFlexible to Model.RFP.DatesFlexible). Silly question: do you have the checkbox and submit button wrapped in a form?

Comment: Yes, I have a form and other values are set as expected. To clarify, you are saying it *is* posting back the values of the checkbox when you test? Is your field of type `bool?`?

Comment: Yep, no problems. I edited my answer so you can see all my code. Heading to bed now, so good luck. I'll check on you tomorrow :)

Comment: D'oh! Right you are. I had forgot to add "RFP." to the beginning of the first string argument. That did correct it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, I think it would help to understand how `Html.CheckBox` works. It's not quite what you'd expect. Take a look at [HTML.CheckBox Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437203/html-checkbox-behaviour/8437258#8437258)

To answer your question, the reason your code doesn't work is because your  `<input />` requires a `value='true'` to bind correctly. For example:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='RFP.DatesFlexible' value='true' />
```

And add a `checked='checked'` property if it should be checked.

That's why I usually override the `Html.CheckBox`method with my own. The default implementation is just confusing.

Comment: Yes, that is confusing. I've edited my question to show the actual code I ended up using. I was still able to use the `@Html` syntax, as it offers some benefits. And, sure enough, if I examine the markup, it does contain the attribute `value='true'`.

Comment: @JonathanWood Your actual code above looks perfect, that's exactly what I would have done.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's marked as accepted however I had the similar problem but I was iterating over sub items so I had problem with the name parameter bool?    isOpen

When I used this is did bind to the ViewModel on post but rendered the dropdown:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Days[i].isOpen)
```

This rendered the checkbox but values where null in the post:

```
@Html.EditorFor("isOpen", model.Days[i].isOpen ?? false)
```

By looking at the rendered html I did this in the view which solved it:

```
@Html.CheckBox("Days[" + i +"].isOpen", Model.Days[i].isOpen ?? false)
```

I know it's know it's a bit quick n dirty but it worked

Hope this helps someone somewhere.