# MVC2 - How to get checkbox data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Okay, right now I have a form that contains this select list:

```
<%=Html.LabelFor(x => x.Id)%>
    <%= Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Ids, new SelectList(Model.Items, "ID", "Name", Model.Ids)) %><br />
```

And here is my controller, where I add the data to the database:

```
foreach (var id in model.Ids)
            {
                tool.ToolItems.Add(new ToolItem { ID = id });
            }
```

Now, I decided to use checkboxes instead of a selectlist, here is that code:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.Tools)
       { %>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tool" value="<%= item.ID %>" />
            <%= tool.Name %>
        </>
    <% } %><br />
```

I have no idea what to do in my controller tho to get all the selected checkboxes.

Sorry if some of the variables dont make sense, I tried to change it as consistently as possible since I cant post the actual stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the following question helpful: [Passing checkbox selection through to an action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089558/passing-checkbox-selection-through-to-an-action/8090259#8090259)

To answer your question, your controller action probably needs to look like this:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string[] tool) {
    // "tool" will contain the values of all checked boxes!
}
```