# How to correctly submit checkbox values to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC web application, and I need to submit `List<ProdColor>` to `Controller` using `checkbox`s. Here is my code

**Model**

```
public partial class ProdColor
{
    public int ProdColor_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> P_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Color_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ProdctModelView ProdctModelView { get; set; }
}

public class ProdctModelView
{
    public ProdctModelView()
    {
        this.ProductColors = new HashSet<ProdColor>();
    }

    public int P_ID { get; set; }
    public string P_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProdColor> ProductColors { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.colorlist = db.Colors.OrderBy(m => m.Color_name).ToList();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProdctModelView product, List<ProdColor> ProductColors)
{
    Product prod = new Product();
    //Save new product
    db.Products.Add(prod);
    db.SaveChanges();

    foreach (var color in ProductColors)
    {        
        color.P_ID = prod.P_ID;
        db.ProdColors.Add(color);
     }
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**View**

```
@model mvc4test.Models.ProdctModelView
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "CP_Product", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.colorlist.Count; i++)
    {                      
        <input type="checkbox" id="@ViewBag.colorlist[i].Color_name" name="[@i].Color_ID" value="@ViewBag.colorlist[i].Color_id"/>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

The problem is when submitting the checkboxes without selecting the *first* one, the value of `List<ProdColor>` become `Null`. So how should I get the correct values at the `Controller`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does this existing question help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220020/how-to-handle-checkboxes-in-asp-net-mvc-forms?rq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You manually creating checkboxes with indexers. Unchecked checkboxes do not post back a value, so if any of the checkboxes are unchecked, you get non-consecutive indexers so model binding fails.

Your model (view model) needs to include a `boolean` property (say) `public bool IsSelected { get; set; }` so that in the view you can use the `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` method to strongly bind to your model.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ColorList.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ColorList[i].Color_id)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ColorList[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ColorList[i].IsSelected, Model.ColorList[i].Color_name)
}
```

The `CheckBoxFor()` method generates a checkbox with `value="true"` and an associated hidden input with `value="false"`. If the checkbox is checked, both `true` and `false` are posted, but only the first (`true`) value is bound. If the checkbox is unchecked, the only `false` is posted.

Then in the POST method, you can get the ID's of the selected items using (say)

```
var selectedColors = product.ColorList.Where(c => c.IsSelected).Select(c => c.Color_id);
```

Note that you do not need a parameter in your POST method for `List<ProdColor> ProductColors` since parameter `ProdctModelView product` already contains all those values.

Comment: This was immensely helpful when dealing with multiple rows of check boxes in a single form. The classic technique of indexing didn't bind the array correctly when the first checkbox wasn't selected, so breaking it out like this was the way to go